# Express - combine routers

Tags: reactjs, express, redux

1 - Goal

What I am trying to achieve is the main dashboard to display the profile of the logged-in user and the other profiles as well as the posts. Similar to the Linkedin dashboard once you are logged in.
However, the dashboard is inaccessible until the user creates a profile.

2 - Attempt

At the moment I only have:

Get all router

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allProfiles = await Profile.find().populate("user", [
      "name",
      "avatar",
    ]);
    res.json(allProfiles);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server not working");
  }
});
```

and a user profile router

```
router.get("/me", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //see if there is a profile
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({
      user: req.user.id,
    }).populate("user", ["name", "avatar"]);

    if (!profile) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "There is no profile for this user " });
    }
    //get profile data
    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

In theory, my idea is to create a combination between the two routers, however, I don't know how to do that.

```
router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //see if there is a profile
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({
      user: req.user.id,
    }).populate("user", ["name", "avatar"]);

    if (!profile) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "There is no profile for this user " });
    }

    //if there is a profile show other profiles
    const allProfiles = await Profile.find().populate("user", [
      "name",
      "avatar",
    ]);

    //How to combine the two ???
    //profile.push(allProfiles);

    res.json(profile);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server not working");
  }
});
```

3 - Issues

I have tested the dashboard and it works perfectly fine if an I connect with the user API only, "/me". However, it does not accommodate the other profiles on the same page. Hence my thought in creating a combined router.

Dashboard Component -

```
const Dashboard = ({
  getProfile,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, loading },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
  }, [getProfile]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading && profile === null ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          {profile !== null ? (
            <ProfileDashboard profile={profile} />
          ) : (
            <NoProfile userName={user && user.name} />
          )}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Sorry for the long post, hope it makes sense. I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Why not just keep two separate routes but do 2 calls to the backend from your dashboard component?

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right yes that's was the right answer !!!! I was complicating things